# Show image out of WAR application

Tags: java, image, jsp, struts, war

I am working in a Struts application and I need to show an image in the JSP that is contained out of the WAR content.

The application is running from:

```
/servicios/was7/watt/instalado/app.WAR
```

And the image is placed in:

```
/servicios/was7/watt/compartido/plantillas_prmifid/T_ES_MIFID_26052008.jpg
```

I don't know how to access by the attribute `src` of the `<img>` tag to the required path.  How to form the path for the image?

Comment: You need to stream the image back from a servlet after opening the image as a resource.

Comment: I want to show the image in a dialog. Have I to create a independent servlet to show the image and set in src attribute the address of the servlet??

Comment: *"show the image in a dialog."*  To who - the user, whose HTML dialogs do not support showing images, or the headless server that does not even have a screen?

Comment: Show an image in a jquery-ui dialog. The image is out of WAR content and it´s not reachable using src attribute. Thanks

Comment: @AlexCuervo It's still going to the HTML DOM; it doesn't matter if it's in a dialog or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSR 315: You can load resources from /META-INF/resources from the Context of your Webapplication.

This does only works on web-xml from version 3.0.

You see: no need to place resources out of the war.